# Who is the woman in the first scene of Ant-Man?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-identification, ant-man, ant-man-2015

In the first scene of *Ant-Man*,

> Hank Pym storms into a room where there are three people: Mitchell Carson, Howard Stark, and a woman.

Who is the woman?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Peggy Carter.**

Here’s a screen cap from the opening scene:

[image]

The actress is Hayley Atwell (albeit with heavy makeup to give the impression of age). She’s shown up a few times in the MCU, including *Captain America: The First Avenger* and *Agent Carter*.

In *Agent Carter*, we see her involved with the SSR, which eventually becomes SHIELD. This includes working with Howard Stark, who’s with her in the early Triskelion. As such, it’s not surprising that we’d see her in a meeting of senior SHIELD members.

Answer (score 10):

The three people are Mitchell Carson, Howard Stark, and Margaret "Peggy" Carter. You may have seen her as a young woman in *[Captain America: The First Avenger](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0458339/)* or in the TV show *[Marvel's Agent Carter](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3475734/)* and as a 92-year-old woman during *[Captain America: The Winter Soldier](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3475734/)*.

Peggy Carter is portrayed by actress Hayley Atwell.

Answer (score -1):

Peggy Carter; although aged from the first Captain America movie.

Comment: Could you add any references to support this?

Comment: Although you're not wrong, I fail to any value in posting this given that the two answers above already say the same thing

Comment: No offense meant, but it was just a matter a consensus. To nitpick, you forgot to add the word "see" in your reply